# Heroku login doesn't work well in git bash

Tags: git, heroku

When I try to `heroku login` in `git bash`

It works like below.

```
heroku: Press any key to open up the browser to login or q to exit:<br>
heroku: Waiting for login...<br>
Logging in... done<br>
Logged in as "my email"<br>
```

And it doesn't pass  to next command.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if [issue 84](https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/84) can help:

> for `git-bash`, I prefer alias for `heroku` cmd like this one:

```
alias heroku='winpty /c/tools/heroku/bin/heroku.cmd'
```

> (my path for `heroku.cmd` is `C:\tools\heroku\bin\heroku.cmd`), stored in `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\.bashrc`.
>   And them I can simple using `heroku cmd` in git-bash like `heroku login` / `heroku auth`:login without any additional tricks.

But... the same issue indicated last month (Nov. 2018):

> The new login will not have this issue as it does not prompt for a password.
>   It should be GA in a few weeks, but for now you can switch to it with `heroku update beta && heroku login`

Answer (score 0):

taken from github discussion

in my case "heroku login -i" worked

https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/1145

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.